# Cómo puedo devolver específicas letras aleatoria?

Tags: python

Cual seria la mejor manera de devolver letras específicas pero a la misma vez esas letras aleatorias, por ejemplo de la distancia a hasta f [a,b,c,d,e,f]. Yo se cómo hacerlo con todo el alfabeto usando la función `random` y `string.ascii_letters`, pero no entiendo como hacerlo específico.

```
 def gen():
    return random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)


# prints the first digits until %s, and starts printing random generation.
def printme():
    combo1 = '999999991468%s111%s1%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s' % (
        gen().upper(), gen().upper(), gen().upper(),
        gen().upper(), gen().upper(), gen().upper(),
        gen().upper(), gen().upper(), gen().upper(),
        gen().upper(), gen().upper(), gen().upper(),
        gen().upper(), gen().upper(), gen().upper(),
        gen().upper(), gen().upper()
    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer exactamente igual pero usando el subconjunto que quieras. Por ejemplo:

```
def gen():
    return random.choice(list('abcdef'))
```

Comment: muchas gracias.